# Cache question help me here?

Tags: cpu-cache, memory-hardware

Quantify the effect in performance which comes from using the cache ,if We are going to use a program which is made from 500 machine instructions ,from which 100 are in a cycle which is executed 25 times.Suppose that the main memory has a memory stall of 10 units of time and the cache memory has a stall of 1 unit.

So the performance equation in this case would be:

CPU exe time=I*(CPI exe + Miss rate * (Memory accesses/Instruction)* Miss penalty )* Clock cycle time

**Is this the right performance formula I should use for this case?**

Miss penalty in my opinion = 10+1 =11

I=500

Memory accesses/Instruction= 25/100

Are these correct?

How do I find Miss rate and clock cycle time here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clock cycle** can be the base unit. That is, the "running time" can be measured in clocks, so a valid answer would be 1000clock cycles  (and not, 10 milliseconds, unless you are given that 1clock-cycle is xx seconds.)

**Miss rate:**
assume each time you read an instruction for the first time, it is a miss. If you read the same instruction for the second time, assume it is already in the cache.  (Otherwise, one must specify the size of the cache and give you more details to decide about miss/hit)

Thus, the 100 instructions that appear in cycle will be a miss for the first time, and a hit in the other 24 times.

The other 400 instructions are always a miss (but they are called only once).

So the miss rate would be.. ?

Comment: I am also worried if my performance equation is alright? Is this the right performance equation I should use?
I still dont understand miss rate.So Miss rate=1-Hit rate,hit rate is related to the 100 instructions where we have a hit 24 times.I guess hit rate is 100/24 ?

Comment: hit rate: (24*100) / (400+ 25*100) ; (must be at most 1!); you equation: It's really hard for me to answer, it seems your question is missing many important detail that ma affect this equation.

Comment: I think that I got this wrong,reading carefully the question I noticed that I need to find the performance without using the cache,then the performance using the cache then find the ratio

Comment: I guess I need to find the first pass which will be all through main memory 500 * 10 = 5000 units. Without cache, the remaining 24 passes through the loop would also be main memory each time;
24 x 100 x 10 = 24,000 units; 29,000 total.

With cache, the same 24 passes would take 24 x 100 x 1 = 2400 units; total 7,400 units.

That is 0.255 the execution time of the uncached version or a saving of 74.5%.

Is this correct?